# Remore rows from pandas dataframe with logics based on multiple column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this,

```
EmpID        ConcatCol  JobSequence
121          TER_DEA      0
121          TER_HSA      0
101          TER_DEA      0
110          TER_HSA      0
111          TER_DEA      1
111          ABC_DEF      0
111          A1_BCD       0
```

All the columns have a dtype of object.

Rule 1:-
If an EmpID has more than 1 record and one of the record has a JobSequence of 1 then remove the other corresponding emp ID records.

The output after rule 1

```
EmpID        ConcatCol  JobSequence
121          TER_DEA      0
121          TER_HSA      0
101          TER_DEA      0
110          TER_HSA      0
111          TER_DEA      1
```

Rule 2

If an EmpID has more than 1 record and one of the record has a ConcatCol of TER_DEA then remove it else maintain that record.

This is the expected output

```
EmpID        ConcatCol   JobSequence
121          TER_HSA      0
101          TER_DEA      0
110          TER_HSA      0
111          TER_DEA      1
```

Every column needs to be in the form of an object

Comment: Do you ask how to do it, or how to do it in a specific way?

Comment: How to do it actually. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we can put this into a function where we sort duplicates by `JobSequence` and whether or not the value is equal to `TER_DEA`, largest first and just take the largest. Then we `groupby` the `EmpID` and use that function:

```
def drop(df):
    return df.assign(x=df['ConcatCol'] == "TER_DEA")\
             .sort_values(["JobSequence", "x"], ascending=False)\
             .drop(columns=["x"])\
             .iloc[0]

df.groupby("EmpID", as_index=False).apply(drop)
#    EmpID ConcatCol  JobSequence
# 0    101   TER_DEA            0
# 1    110   TER_HSA            0
# 2    111   TER_DEA            1
# 3    121   TER_DEA            0
```

This assumes that your `JobSequence` column is numeric or at least sorts properly. If it is not, make it so, at least temporarily, using `.assign(JobSequence=pd.to_numeric(df["JobSequence"]))`.

Comment: Sorting here is not really necessary, you can solve this problem in O(n).

Comment: @cglacet: You are right, and the other answer seems indeed to be O(n). Which one is easier to read is left to the reader, but if you do need that last bit of performance then sure. Or maybe you have another O(n) solution in mind, in which case, please post it so I can upvote it as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can have O(n) without having anything too complex by iterating manually over the input (a constant number of times).

Comment: @cglacet: Manually iterating over the rows of a `pandas` data frame is almost guaranteed to be orders of magnitude slower than using the built-in vectorized methods. So the dataframe would need to be very large to make it worth it (possibly larger than memory).

Comment: I don't know pandas so I'll have to trust you on this one. But how do they manage to have iterators/generators that are log n times faster? If that's the case then I guess sorting is just fine ^^.

Comment: @cglacet: The `pandas` methods are so much faster because they are implemented in C and operate directly on the `numpy` arrays in memory, whereas manually iterating over the rows is performed in Python, at Python speed. And I would guess the number of duplicates of each employee will be small, hopefully less than a hundred, and being a factor of `ln(100) = 4.6` faster is easy for C vs Python.

Comment: As far as I know, Python iterators tools are all written in C. I agree on the fact that log n is probably small enough here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it. Start by defining the following conditions in order to perform boolean indexation on the dataframe:

```
c1 = df.EmpID.duplicated(keep=False) & df.JobSequence.eq(1)
c2 = c1.groupby(df.EmpID).transform('any')

df.assign(c1=c1, c2=c2)

   EmpID ConcatCol  JobSequence     c1     c2
0    121   TER_DEA            0  False  False
1    121   TER_HSA            0  False  False
2    101   TER_DEA            0  False  False
3    110   TER_HSA            0  False  False
4    111   TER_DEA            1   True   True
5    111   ABC_DEF            0  False   True
6    111    A1_BCD            0  False   True
```

You can obtain the expected dataframe after having applied  *Rule 1*  taking the `XNOR` based on both the above conditions:

```
df1 = df[~(c1 ^ c2)]

    EmpID ConcatCol  JobSequence
0    121   TER_DEA            0
1    121   TER_HSA            0
2    101   TER_DEA            0
3    110   TER_HSA            0
4    111   TER_DEA            1
```

And for  *Rule 2*, you can do:

```
siz = df1.groupby('EmpID').ConcatCol.transform('size')
df1[~(siz.gt(1) & df1.ConcatCol.eq('TER_DEA'))]

    EmpID ConcatCol  JobSequence
1    121   TER_HSA            0
2    101   TER_DEA            0
3    110   TER_HSA            0
4    111   TER_DEA            1
```